# Por que el codigo no funciona con numeros grandes

Tags: python

este es un pequeño código en python para comprobar el numero mas grande de entre tres números que el usuario ingresa, el código funciona bien si los tres números están por debajo de 3 cifras, es decir hasta 100, pero cuando se ingresa un numero mas alto que 100 no lo escoge aun siendo claro que son mas grande, pro favor ayuda, soy principiante.

```
def max_num():
    num1 = input("Ingresa el primer numero: ")
    num2 = input("Ingresa el segundo numero: ")
    num3 = input("Ingresa el tercer numero: ")

    if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
       return num1
    elif num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3:
       return num2
    elif num3 >= num1 and num3 >= num2:
       return num3

print(max_num())
```

Comment: Qué resultado te da, cuál esperas? Te da error? Lee [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/)

Comment: Después de corregir el problema de indentación, lo probe y funciona como se espera. No veo ninguna falla.

Comment: No necesitas hacer el tercer "if". A esas alturas no queda otra que num3 sea el mayor.

Comment: si, el else if final no es necesario, basta con un else, con numeros superiores a 100 no funcionaba, era por que no estaba convertido a integer como dijo Fazzano

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lo que pasa es que estás comparando Strings en vez de integer. Para solucionarlo tenés que transformar tus input() en int.

Utilizando tu código te quedaría así:

```
def max_num():
    num1 = int(input("Ingresa el primer numero: "))
    num2 = int(input("Ingresa el segundo numero: "))
    num3 = int(input("Ingresa el tercer numero: "))

    if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
        return num1

    elif num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3:
        return num2

    elif num3 >= num1 and num3 >= num2:
        return num3


print(max_num())
```

Comment: Gracias! :) ahora si sirve, se me olvido que por defecto lo recibe como string